# cellForRowAtIndexPath not returning cell objective c

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, xcode, uitableview

Iam facing a issue with the cellForRowAtIndexPath not returning cell.

Below is my service output

```
(
 {
     AcNo = 667;
     Avg = 2;
     Address = New York;
     busReviews =         (
                           {
                               Id = 270;
                               businessName = "Pharmacy Inc";
                               comment = "Good Product.";
                           },
                           {
                               Id = 269;
                               businessName = "Agro Buss Inc";
                               comment = "Looks like a great product.";
                               }
                           );
 }
 )
```

When i tried to retrieve the data in a table view for busReviews. It only displays the first record not the second record.

Below is what i have tried. Please help me to find the issue. TIA

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";
  UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
        if (cell == nil) {
            cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:@"CellIdentifier"];
 }
 NSMutableDictionary * thisRow = [detailsarr objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];


        times = [thisRow objectForKey:@"busReviews"];


        NSMutableDictionary* refilldict = [times objectAtIndex:0];

        NSString *column1 = [refilldict objectForKey:@"businessName"];

         NSString *column2 = [refilldict objectForKey:@"comment"];



        reviewname.text=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@%@",@"-by ",column1];
        review.text= [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",column2];


        cell.selectionStyle=UITableViewCellSelectionStyleGray;


       return cell;
    }
    return nil;
}
```

Comment: can you show the `detailsarr` OP

Comment: `reviewname` and `review` being? They are not property of your cell?

Comment: It displays only the first record because you are retrieving only the first record (`[times objectAtIndex:0]`). By the way: If there is no record you will get an *out-of-range* exception.

Comment: show some additional code